# How to bind untyped datatables to RDLC reports?

Tags: datatable, rdlc, strongly-typed-dataset

Is there a way to bind untyped DataTables to RDLC reports? As far as I've seen, It's just possible to use strongly typed DataSets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind strongly-typed datasets, and objects, because they have a full type description at design-time. Untyped datasets by their nature don't have this.